# looping in sql with delimiter

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr

I just had this idea of how can i loop in sql?

For example 
I have this column

**PARAMETER_VALUE**
 `E,C;S,C;I,X;G,T;S,J;S,F;C,S;`

i want to store all value before (,) in a temp column also store all value after (;) into another column
then it wont stop until there is no more value after  (;)

*Expected Output for Example*

**COL1** `E S I G S S C`

**COL2** `C C X T J F S`

etc . . .

Comment: Change your data model / design. Distinct values should be represented by storing them as separate columns and not jumbled together into a string with a delimiter. You'll keep facing problems due to this as evident from the abundance of questions similar to yours here in SO.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want the result to have two columns and a **single** row, with the values `'E S I G S S C'` and `'C C X T J F S'` (strings of letters separated by space)? Or do you want the output to have two columns and **seven** rows, and each value (each row/column intersection) to be just one letter? Only the latter makes sense - if it's the former, I would wonder why you would want to do that in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you need to separate the input into rows, at the `;` delimiters, and then into columns at the `,` delimiter, you could do something like this:

```
-- WITH clause included to simulate input data. Not part of the solution;
-- use actual table and column names in the SELECT statement below.
with 
  t1(id, parameter_value) as (
    select 1, 'E,C;S,C;I,X;G,T;S,J;S,F;C,S;' from dual union all
    select 2, ',U;,;V,V;'                    from dual union all
    select 3, null                           from dual
  )
-- End of simulated input data
select  id,
        level as ord,
        regexp_substr(parameter_value, '(;|^)([^,]*),', 1, level, null, 2) as col1,
        regexp_substr(parameter_value, ',([^;]*);'    , 1, level, null, 1) as col2
from    t1
connect by  level <= regexp_count(parameter_value, ';') 
        and id = prior id 
        and prior sys_guid() is not null
order   by id, ord
;

 ID ORD COL1 COL2
--- --- ---- ----
  1   1 E    C   
  1   2 S    C   
  1   3 I    X   
  1   4 G    T   
  1   5 S    J   
  1   6 S    F   
  1   7 C    S   
  2   1      U   
  2   2          
  2   3 V    V   
  3   1
```

Note - this is not the most efficient way to split the inputs (nothing will be very efficient - the data model, which is in violation of First Normal Form, is the reason). This can be improved using standard `instr` and `substr`, but the query will be more complicated, and for that reason, harder to maintain.

I generated more input data, to illustrate a few things. You may have several inputs that must be broken up at the same time; that must be done with care. (Note the additional conditions in CONNECT BY). I also illustrate the handling of NULL - if a comma comes right after a semicolon, that means that the "column 1" part of that pair must be NULL. That is shown in the output.

Comment: Hi @mathguy, what if i only have comma separated values? then each values goes to separate column. like ='E,C,G,SMS' then column 1= E, column 2=C etc.

Comment: @JeannellCasaje - that is a different question (even though it may seem similar to you); if you have a different question, post it here in a new thread. Feel free to refer to this thread, although that may not be too important, since the problems are really different (when you use the same delimiter to mark row ends and column separation).

Answer (score 2):

You can get by using `regexp_substr()` window analytic function with `connect by level <=` clause

```
with t1(PARAMETER_VALUE) as
(
 select 'E,C;S,C;I,X;G,T;S,J;S,F;C,S;' from dual
), t2 as
( 
select level as rn,
       regexp_substr(PARAMETER_VALUE,'([^,]+)',1,level) as str1,
       regexp_substr(PARAMETER_VALUE,'([^;]+)',1,level) as str2
  from t1
connect by level <= regexp_count(PARAMETER_VALUE,';') 
)
select listagg( regexp_substr(str1,'([^;]+$)') ,' ') within group (order by rn) as col1,
       listagg( regexp_substr(str2,'([^,]+$)') ,' ') within group (order by rn) as col2 
  from t2;

COL1            COL2
-------------   -------------
E S I G S S C   C C X T J F S
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=976b00cc9a26aa15239daad038e6cdb2)</kbd>